# What databatases support event subscriptions?

Tags: database, notifications, real-time-updates

Which data storage systems I can use in order to implement real-time notifications through subscriptions? Be it notifications about data updates, or custom messages with payload.

Surprisingly, there is no answer to this question, at least, not in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to kolypo's answer...

[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) is really straight forward to get setup and has really nice realtime features for both mobile and web.

[AWS AppSync](https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) is another option for setting up pub/sub. I've not used it, but it's appealing if your org is already married in the AWS stack.

[Couchbase](https://www.couchbase.com/) allows realtime queries but I've found it has data synchronization issues in mobile scenarios where connectivity isn't stable

Answer (score 0):

[Redis](https://redis.io/): an in-memory key/value store. It can do [blocking-pop](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) from a list, and also supports [PubSub](https://redis.io/commands#pubsub). This enables you to build a queue of items: e.g. serialized strings.

[Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/): a relational database. [NOTIFY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) supports sending named events with a payload. These can be sent from triggers that react on insert/update/delete actions.

[MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/). A NoSQL document database. Supports [Change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) that lets you subscribe to a collection0 (≈database) and receive updates about created documents.

[EventStore](https://www.eventstore.com/). A store for [event-sourcing](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html). Supports [subscriptions to event streams](https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/grpc/subscriptions.html).

[RethinkDB](https://rethinkdb.com/) supports realtime queries: i.e. a long-running query that sends results as they arrive. Unfortunately, the project seems dead as of 2021.